# coherence intersection circles and lorentz-factor

Tags: geometry

In an addition to my previous question about intersecting circles I like to ask what you think of this.

The formulas for eccentricity and the lorentz-factor are quite similar.

[image: lorentz vs ellips]

So I used the variable eccentricity of the ellips produced by the dynamically intersecting circles, to extract the lorentz-factor.

v = velocity and c= propagation velocity of light.

This is what I calculated.

[image: calculation of Y]

Interesting is that the intersecting circles reveal the geometrical proportions of Einstein's (γ-1) used for formulating kinetic energy in e=mc²(γ-1);

a/f = (γ-1)

[image: infinity]

The sequence also shows that when v=c the circles no longer intersect.
At this point (γ-1) results in infinite energy. (Preventing mass from reaching the speed of light)

My question is: When applied to velocity is the following true?

a/f= (γ-1)

when f=0

a/0= ∞

a/f= (γ-1)

∞ = ∞ -1

∞ = ∞ -1 can only be true for infinity and not for any other number.

The picture shows that to be able to successfully apply the lorentz-factor it requires a body traveling the path v not to have own dimensions. Regarding the fact that c can't depart from the center of a body. I assume that the infinity barrier is merely a mathematical result based on the same requirement of zero dimension, and therefore can not be a physical reality.

Perhaps one of you guys can prove that easily, or just prove me wrong here. Thanks.

Comment: Congratulations, you have stumbled across "Geometric Relativity". A coherent description for this is currently being researched.

Try this. Create an ellipsoid (sphere) with 2 static axis and 1 axis that can grow or shrink. Treat the 2 static axis as representing the speed of light (their values are equal to c). Using the desired velocity, calculate the Lorentz term. Set the length of the 3rd axis equal to c divided by the Lorentz term. The ellipsoid now reflects the appropriate length contraction, as if it were traveling that velocity. Eccentricity = time dilation = length contraction.

Comment: In addition, if one treats the speed of light (or any velocity) as the ratio of the radius to the volume of a sphere, this ratio will remain constant for the 3rd axis (3rd radius) and the changing volume of the ellipsoid. Meaning, the ratio of the variable 3rd axis to the variable volume of the ellipsoid is constant. Just like the speed of light. This is not the case for the other axis. Just the "relativistic" axis. 

In this consideration, time is treated as volume. Spacetime.